# Drupal - views Slideshow not working on front page(panel)

Tags: javascript, ajax, drupal

On my Drupal site I created a sideshow using views.It works fine in every page except on the front page.My front page is a panel node.Can some one give me a solution please ??
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a cache problem with the panel. Panels might cache the view, code and then not generate the javascript for the homepage to enable the slideshow.

YOu can try turning off, or tuning the cache for the block in the panel for the front page.

Comment: It can be done in the performance page right??
My
Caching mode : Disabled

Comment: if you go into panels, then content for the page you are editing. Where you have a list of the blocks, click on the cog in the top right hand corner of the block, and goto simple cache and check the settings, either disable it for that block, or try the argument/context options. I would also check if the javascript used to setup the slideshow is present on the frontpage, if it is, then this might not be your problem